# To create user defined Exceptions

Tags: exception

I was trying to create a USER DEFINED EXCEPTION in the below code, but it is not working . Please correct where i am going wrong.
The error i am getting is 'check' not defined. I am unable to understand.

class MyException(Exception):
def **init**(self,arg):
self.msg=arg
def check(x):
for k,v in check.items():
print('Name={} Balance={}'.format(k,v))
if(v<2000):
raise MyException('Balance amt is less in the account of ',k)

bank={'Raj':5000,'Vikas':10000,'Nishit':500,'John':321211}

try:
check(bank)
except MyException as obj:
print(obj)

Comment: In what langiuage?

Answer (score 0):

"check" is your function name,dont have “items” method.What you want to check its items is the argument "x"

code:

```
class MyException(Exception): 
    def init(self,arg): 
        self.msg=arg 

def check(x): 
    for k,v in x.items(): 
        print('Name={} Balance={}'.format(k,v)) 
        if(v<2000): 
            raise MyException('Balance amt is less in the account of ',k)

bank={'Raj':5000,'Vikas':10000,'Nishit':500,'John':321211}

try: 
    check(bank) 
except MyException as obj: 
    print(obj)
```

result:

```
Name=Raj Balance=5000
Name=Vikas Balance=10000
Name=Nishit Balance=500
('Balance amt is less in the account of ', 'Nishit')
```

if you want to continue after throw exception,show John as well

code:

```
class MyException(Exception): 
    def __init__(self,arg): 
        self.msg=arg 

def check(key,value): 
    print('Name={} Balance={}'.format(key,value)) 
    if(v<2000): 
        raise MyException(f'Balance amt is less in the account of {key}')

bank={'Raj':5000,'Vikas':10000,'Nishit':500,'John':321211}
for k,v in bank.items(): 
    try: 
        check(k,v) 
    except MyException as obj: 
        print(obj)
```

result:

```
Name=Raj Balance=5000
Name=Vikas Balance=10000
Name=Nishit Balance=500
Balance amt is less in the account of Nishit
Name=John Balance=321211
```

Comment: Still i am getting same error 'check' is not defined

Comment: Also why John is not getting displayed in your solution

Comment: @Chayan Mehrotra 1.please show your code in correct indent style,python use indent to identify code block.And which line got error 'check' is not defined? 2.John is after Nishit,which throw an exception to end the check function,so John was displayed

Comment: how to display John also , pls help

Comment: @Chayan Mehrotra,already edit to display John.

Comment: i understood the problem when i m using self.msg=arg i am not getting any error , but whn i m using self.arg=arg i m getting error. Please explain me this concept

Comment: @Chayan Mehrotra,please show error message, "self.arg=arg" works fine to me.